# Phonegap RPC setup issue

Tags: gwt, cordova, rpc

I am trying to get ann RPC call to work with phonegap. I am following the instructions on http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-rpc-with-phonegap-revisited.html

```
PhonegapUtil.prepareService(service, "http://www.yourserver.com/", "greet");
```

When I look in the implementation of this method I can see that the service must be of type PhonegapRPCService or it will throw an error. The implementation has the following code

```
if (!(service instanceof PhonegapRPCService)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("the rpc service you are trying to use was not generated by Phonegap RPC Serivce Generator");
```

Here is my code so far

```
      ContactsServiceAsync rpcService = GWT.create(ContactsService.class);
  ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) rpcService;    
  PhonegapUtil.prepareService(endpoint, "https://myquizapp2.appspot.com/", "contactsService");
  HandlerManager eventBus = new HandlerManager(null);
  AppController appViewer = new AppController(rpcService, eventBus);
  appViewer.go(RootPanel.get());
```

problem is I don't see how to create a PhonegapRPCService instance that will call into my contactsService service on my server. Any ideas on how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted is correct. You don't have to create a PhonegapRPCService instance.
PhonegapUtil.prepareService needs ServiceDefTarget instance, which you already have.
If the url that you provide is correct this works.